# how to send javascript variable data to a php file while loading the same page

Tags: javascript, php

i have 2 php files named as A.php and B.php. i need to send same data values in javascript at A.php to B.php, simple i am using below post array for that.

```
$.post('B.php', {sendlat: sendlat, sendlng: sendlng});
```

but when i sending the data to the B.php. once sending has complete i need to open the B.php file and display the posted data on the page.

can is use the session i hope no? 
any possible method ?

i have tried to use below method to load the file, it happened but i cant receive the data from the post array?

```
  window.location = "B.php";
```

kindly give me a suggestion, am so appreciate if you can give me a coding example for this.

thank you 
chamath

Comment: Just submit the form normally instead of using AJAX. Sends the data AND moves the user to that page

Comment: can i use general HTML form submission within the js, all the data fielsds are in js variable format

Comment: can u use some logic, by the way of using session ...

Comment: `<form action="B.php" method="post">`

Answer (score -2):

The point of Ajax is to make an HTTP request *without* leaving the page.

If you want to navigate to the page you get as a result of making the POST request: Don't use Ajax.

Just use a regular form submission instead.

You can generate the form from JS DOM manipulation and call its `submit()` method if you want to do this programatically.